# Module with Providers as a package dependency on node_modules

Tags: angular, angular-services, packages.json

I have a Module with Providers in a package dependency. But when I try to use it in my app.module I get:

```
Error: No provider for EnvService!
```

**/node_modules/common-components/env.module:**

```js
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { WindowService } from './window.service';
import { EnvService } from './env.service';

export function windowFactory() {
  return window;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class EnvModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: EnvModule,
      providers: [
        EnvService,
        { provide: WindowService, useFactory: windowFactory }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { EnvModule } from 'common-components';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    EnvModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the `EnvService` in the providers of the module as well:

```js
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { WindowService } from './window.service';
import { EnvService } from './env.service';

export function windowFactory() {
  return window;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    EnvService
  ]
})
export class EnvModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: EnvModule,
      providers: [
        EnvService,
        { provide: WindowService, useFactory: windowFactory }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did your suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Comment: can you post the EnvService? Is it decorated with @Injectable()?

Comment: yes, I have it:
@Injectable()
export class EnvService { }

Comment: If I use the env.module inside the `/app` it works, but using as a package.json dependency I get the error.

Comment: Are you using from `node_modules/service-package`?

Comment: thank you. I solved the problem. In this case, providers of the module is not necessary.